# How to intercept a cancelled http request in Angular?

Tags: angular, http, angular-http-interceptors

Angular cancels http requests very fast and I want to intercept those cancelled requests. **Is it possible to capture cancelled requests in the interceptor?** 
Below is a fragment of my interceptor code, where I want to catch cancelled request.

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.onStartRequest();
    // Pass the cloned request instead of the original request to the next handle
    return next.handle(req).do(
      (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
         // do something
        }
      },
      (err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          // do something
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by a 'cancelled request' in this context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handle cancelled http request in angular httpclient interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755818/handle-cancelled-http-request-in-angular-httpclient-interceptor)

Comment: This blog may be used  https://laxmanchavda.blogspot.com/2018/10/intercept-all-http-request-in-angular.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try with the finalize event?

```
return next.handle(req).pipe(
  finalize(() => {
    // request completes, errors, or is cancelled
  })
);
```

Comment: How do I figure out which request, got canceled in finalize? Does it have any specific key in it which shows that the particular request got canceled?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `catchError` RxJs operator when you use the `next` Handler, here's the code:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.onStartRequest();
    // Pass the cloned request instead of the original request to the next handle
    return next.handle(req).do(
      (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
         // do something
        }
      })
      .catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        // Handle errors
      });
  }
```

PS: Don't forget to import the catchError operator.